# show progressbar without bottom button

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, progress-bar, scrollview

I want to create a layout with below features:
I have a `LinearLayout` with `TextView` and `Progressbar` for showing progress UI when activity should to work network task. I mean this layout sometimes is visible and sometimes is gone.

I want a layout in `ScrollView` and a `button` in below page *below in layout*.
I write below code. and button and scrollview shows good but when i set `LinearLayout` for progressBar to visible, layout shows bottom button. I don't want to shows any views when showing progressbar. How can i correct below code for solve this problem. Thanks for advises :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-atuo"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.kit.itil.sdcartable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/TaskDetailActivity_btn_report"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutPb_TaskDetailActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:visibility="gone" >

            <com.kit.helper.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/progressText_TaskDetailActivity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar_TaskDetailActivity"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="70dip"
                android:layout_height="70dip"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:indeterminateBehavior="cycle"
                android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >'

        //...some layout is here...
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/TaskDetailActivity_btn_report"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.kit.helper.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/TaskDetailActivity_TextView_report"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/TaskDetailActivity_TextView_reportBtn"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

While doing network task AsyncTask should be used so that it doesn't start on main UI thread
If AsyncTask is used properly your problem will get resolved.

Please refer to

- [AsyncTask Android example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)